# How to enable WiFi adapter to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line

I was trying to aircrack and realized that my net work adapter wasn’t being recognized in the “Select a network” (Settings) I’ve been at this for almost 5 days trying to fix this, any help?

Comment: This seems to be a common problem for 18.04 try to restart your network manager `sudo service network-manager restart` and when you can detect your wlan try `ifconfig wlan0 down && ifconfig wlan0 up`

Comment: @user535733  Hello, before I send the lshw I need to know how to format it into the comments.

Comment: Not the comments. Edit the original question.